# C++ Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы пользователь вводил значение параметра, для функции

Tags: c++, функции

Всем привет, недавно начал изучать функции, получил задание, решить уравнение с использованием функции  y = exp(1 / x) - log(1 / x);  Как сделать так, чтобы пользователь вводил значение - х, n количество раз(например 5). Пробовал сделать так, но код не запускается :

```
   #include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

float calculate(int x, float y) {
    int c;
    for (c = 0; c < 5; c++) {
        cin >> x;
        y = exp(1 / x) - log(1 / x);
        cout << " Результат для x = " << c << " : exp(1 / x) - log(1 / x) = " << y << endl;
        c++;
    }

}


int main()
{
    calculate();
}
```

Comment: Почему `x` и `y` - параметры функции, а не переменные внутри функции?

Comment: Очевидно же, что он не "не запускается", он в принципе не может быть скомпилирован. Функция `calculate` принимает на вход два параметра, в точке вызова же Вы не передаете ей ни одного.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void calculate(std::istream& in, std::ostream& out, const unsigned n) {
    unsigned x; 
    for (int c = 0; c < n && in >> x; c++) {                
        out << " Результат для x = " << x << " : exp(1 / x) - log(1 / x) = "
            << exp(1.0 / x) - log(1.0 / x) << std::endl;
    }   
}
int main() {    
    calculate(std::cin, std::cout, 5);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Есть еще один вариант (давайте сначала посмотрим на код)

```
#define UNUSED(x) (void)(x)


#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    UNUSED(argc);
    UNUSED(argv);

    int number{};

    auto func = [](int number){std::cout << exp(1.0 / number) - log(1.0 / number) << std::endl;};

    while (std::cin >> number) {
        func(number);
    }

    std::cout << "End of programm" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Тут ввод будет считываться до тех пор пока Вы не отправите прерывание EOF (сочетание клавиш CTRL + D)